# How do I rewrite a URL so it looks like a user is somewhere they're not?

Tags: php, javascript, url, url-rewriting

I have a url, www.mysite.com/register, but when people visit this page, I'd like it to look like they're visiting www.mysite.com/shop/account/register, even though that page doesn't exist.

I'm working in PHP and JS

Thanks

EDIT:

www.mysite.com/register already exists, when a user goes to www.mysite.com/shop/account/register, I'd like it to redirect to the first url but look like they're still visiting /account/shop/register.

Comment: You probably want something like mod-rewrite or mod-alias on Apache, or your webserver's equivalent.

Comment: What now, does the page exist or does it not exist? Or do you mean that the relation between the URI in the browser to the file-system on your webserver is not that obvious?

Comment: Use your .htaccess file of course.

Comment: Just edited my question to be a bit more specific. I have something in my htaccess already which redirects to /register when a user lands on shop/account/register, but the problem is it no longer looks like they're on shop/account/register

Comment: If your server sends back a page when that URL is requested, then a page *does* exist at that URL.  It just has a non-one-to-one relationship with the PHP files on the server's hard drive.

Comment: "I have something in my htaccess already which redirects" — you want an internal URL rewrite, not a redirect.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips, I'll checkout the link provided by Jaspreet and see where I get to.

Answer (score 2):

Ok first thing is that you will need mod_rewrite module enabled within your Apache configuration. Its a long tutorial so I recommend to read this tutorial for beginners

http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/